# Is it possible to control charts in powerpoint using combo box?

Tags: excel, powerpoint, vba

The below image is an example of what i am trying to do. My chart shows the capacity of Resources over month. I choose the month for which i want to view data from the dropdown list. While this is in excel, im trying to do the same in Powerpoint using the charts and AxtiveX controls. Can anyone please guide me on this?

[Chart and combobox example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJyvc.png)

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking, but I'm almost certain the answer is "Yes".  What are you actually trying to accomplish here?  Your application is written presumably in Excel VBE, but then controlling a PPT file in PowerPoint, right? So what do you mean by "trigger chart display"?

Comment: Sorry for not being more clear. I have a chart in powerpoint that shows me the capacity of 4 resources for different months(Jan, Feb and so on). I need users to pick a particular month from a combo box control so that only data related to that month shows up in my chart. For eg: if i choose Jan from my combo box, the chart should display capacity of available resources for jan month only.

Comment: Do you intend to edit your question with more detail/clarity?

Comment: Yep that's definitely possible, but it's still not clear what you mean by "show". You're going to need to elaborate, by editing your question. Please add *more detail* than you think is necessary, and especially add code which you have attempted to impilement (or pseudo-code). This makes it easier for anyone to assist you, since they won't have to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: @DavidZemens i have added an image in my question, which i hope explains what im trying to do.

Comment: No, it doesn't really help me understand at all. Are you trying implementing in PowerPoint directly? If so, do you have similar functional code from Excel (it's relatively easy to adapt your existing Excel VBA to PPT)?

Comment: The one is excel is purely formula based. I chart data is a subset of my data dump(data for all months). If i choose Jan from my dropdown(i have used input range and cell link of form controls), i use vlookup to get Jan data as my chart data. Does this help?

Comment: Can you show the formula? Please **[edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38270750/edit)** the question with this detail, and also include details about how the ActiveX control is configured. Or, it may be even better to upload a sample XLSM file to Google Docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a standard Microsoft Forms 2.0 ComboBox control (I do not use ActiveX controls), this is pretty much what you're looking for.

Insert the ComboBox control on the slide where the chart exists. This assumes that the chart data exists in the default `ListBox` item on the `ChartData.Workbook.Worksheets(1)` worksheet (i.e., this is what happens when you insert a chart directly in PPT) if you're copying a chart from Excel, this may need revision, but the general idea is the same:

1. When the user selects the combobox, (`ComboBox1_GotFocus` queries the chart's underlying data to populate the list. If your data is structured differently, this will need to be modified.
2. User can make a selection in the ComboBox.
3. After making the selection, the `ComboBox1_Change` event will identify the range of data which contains the selected series, and hides the other series, so that only the selected series is visible

Here's my default chart & data which I can view by right-click/Edit Data:

[image]

Displaying the slideshow, entering the ComboBox will display the list of series names:

[image]

Then, change the selection, and see only the selected series:

[image]

```
Option Explicit
'This code belongs in a SLIDE module in PowerPoint
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
'This procedure hides/unhides chart series, based on combobox value
    Dim rng As Object  'Excel.Range object
    Dim c As Long

    With Me.Shapes("Content Placeholder 5").Chart.ChartData  '## MODIFY YOUR SHAPE NAME
        .Activate
        .Workbook.Parent.WindowState = -4140
        For c = 2 To .Workbook.Worksheets(1).ListObjects(1).HeaderRowRange.Columns.Count
            Set rng = .Workbook.Worksheets(1).ListObjects(1).HeaderRowRange.Cells(c)
            rng.EntireColumn.Hidden = (rng.Value <> ComboBox1.Value)
        Next
        .Workbook.Close
    End With

End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_GotFocus()
'This procedure sets the list items in the combobox whenever it gets focus
Dim lst As Variant
Dim xlApp As Object
With Me.Shapes("Content Placeholder 5").Chart.ChartData  '## MODIFY YOUR SHAPE NAME
    .Activate
    .Workbook.Parent.WindowState = -4140
    Set xlApp = .Workbook.Parent
    .Workbook.Worksheets(1).Columns("B:D").Hidden = False
    lst = xlApp.Transpose(xlApp.Transpose(.Workbook.Worksheets(1).Range("B1:D1").Value))
    .Workbook.Close
End With
ComboBox1.List = lst
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow this is great. Exactly what i was looking to do. Thanks a ton for this!! New learning for me.